# xsd of a web service

Tags: web-services, xsd

I need to generate the xsd of a .net web service. Can anyone let me know how I can go about doing it. I have tried using xsd.exe /u:url of the web service. Can anyone tell me if its possible.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure exactly what you're asking so here are a few answers...

If you're looking to generate the code (classes) that will communicate your existing web service - you can use WSDL.exe or SVCUTIL.exe (i.e. `wsdl /c /u:<url of the web service's WSDL> /o:<output directory>`).

If you're looking to get the WSDL (i.e. the XML schema definition of the types and operations that the web service implements) you just need to connect to the web service and add a `?WSDL` to the end of the URL (i.e. `http://www.test.com/yourWebService.asmx?WSDL`).

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

SOAP-based Web Services don't have "an XSD" - they have a WSDL, which will either include or reference one or more XML Schemas.

I do not know of a tool which will extract the WSDL and all schemas for all cases. If your ".NET Web Service" is a legacy ".ASMX" web service, then you can browse to the WSDL by adding "?WSDL" to the end of the service URL. You can then save the document to disk. If the WSDL refers to other WSDL XML Schema documents, then you may be able to browse to them in turn.

If your ".NET Web Service" is a modern, WCF service, and if it is configured to share metadata, then you can use the command:

> svcutil.exe /t:metadata  `<url>`

Answer (score 0):

http://linqtoxsd.codeplex.com/ works best for me.